# Работа с FileStream

Tags: c#, filestream

Господа, подскажите, пожалуйста. Почему не происходит копирования файла?

```
static void Main()
{
    FileStream f = new FileStream(@"D:\1.zip", FileMode.Open);
    FileStream cr = new FileStream(@"D:2.zip", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    byte[] mass = new byte[f.Length];
    f.Read(mass, 0, (int)f.Length);
    cr.Write(mass, 0, mass.Length); cr.Flush(); cr.Close();
}
```

В пошаговой отладке вроде массив создается и инициализируется, как надо. Но при запуске программы даже файла с именем 2.zip не создается. Why?

Comment: D:2.zip - точно слэш не забыли? ;) Ну и OutOfMemoryException выглядывает из третьей строки кода. Посмотрите таки на CopyTo

Comment: Вы забыли в пути второго файла слеш.

Comment: Я думаю, Вам надо @"D:\2.zip" вместо @"D:2.zip" использовать.

Comment: Черт! 100% ВЫ правы. Он накопировал кучу файлов мне в папку с проектом, а не на диск D. Случайно понял, когда поставил FileMode.CreateNew. В эксепшине он сказал, что все в папку с проектом пошло. СПАСИБО огромное товарищи!

Comment: Если 1.zip был большого размера, не забудьте почистить поток d:2.zip. Да, и в любом случае - не дело это, всякую пакость в потоках корневой папки хранить...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот такое исполнение будет в хорошем стиле)))

```
        const int buffersize = 16384;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[buffersize];
        int bytescopied = 0;

        using (FileStream inStream  = File.Open(@"D:\1.zip", 
               FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        using (FileStream outStream = File.Open(@"D:\2.zip",
               FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            do
            {
                bytescopied = inStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffersize);

                if (bytescopied > 0)
                {
                    outStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytescopied);
                }
            }
            while (bytescopied > 0);
        }
```

Comment: @IGOR: В хорошем стиле будет

    File.Copy(@"D:\1.zip", @"D:\2.zip");

(и, кстати, лучше по производительности).

Comment: Мой вариант просто гибче ))Возможность манипуляции байтами напрямую, управлять типами доступа к файлу , посчитать производительность... using гарантирует что файлы будут закрыты в конце каждого блока, не зависимо от того, возникли ли  внутри него исключения)

Comment: @IGOR: если вам нужно обрабатывать файлы по дороге — да, тогда нужно спускаться на уровень байт (а возможно и до десериализации объектной структуры).

`File.Copy` тоже не оставляет потоки открытыми, понятно. Вот [обсуждение](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1247042/276994) по теме, кстати.

А зачем вам управлять доступом? Неужели какая-нибудь другая комбинация атрибутов имеет смысл?